# Hibernate + postgresql + Amazon S3

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

This is my first time to build a web application which are using hibernate and postgresql. I intend using Amazon S3 when I publish the website. So I wonder if I need to change my code dynamically? More specifically, will I be able to hibernate to map with S3 tables? Will S3 supports postgresql? Or straightforwardly, what should I do after I finish my project?

Sorry if those are dumb questions; but this world is so new to me. If there are any resources that would help my knowledge, I would like to deep into it.

Comment: Hibernate ORM is for persistence to relational stores (like PostgreSQL) while S3 is just object storage. It is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Actually, I dont know what to ask since I don't have sufficient knowledge about this field yet. So I post the question with hope that some one would share some their precious knowledge with me.

Comment: And by 'field' what do you mean? 'I intend using Amazon S3 when I publish the website' doesn't really make sense to me as I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve or in what context it means. Why do you want to use S3? What are you trying to accomplish and why are you choosing to use these tools?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confused.

Perhaps you mean [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/), the relational database service for AWS? With RDS it's almost the same as any other PostgreSQL install; just with a few quirks and limitations:

- You don't get true superuser access;
- You can't install custom extensions, you're limited to the ones Amazon provides;
- You can't replicate into or out of RDS or take physical backups / WAL archives into or out of RDS
- You can't log into or control the computer PostgreSQL runs on directly

RDS doesn't run your program, like your Java + Hibernate code. It's just a database. If you want to run your own code you need to host it on EC2 (where you can use RDS for the database, or your own DB install on your EC2 nodes), or use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is an object-store. You store and retrieve files to it. It is not a database in any meaningful sense. It's somewhat more like a *file system* than a database, if anything. It's completely nonsensical to talk about Hibernate with reference to S3. There are no "tables" or "fields" in S3. (You can publish a static website from S3, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do here if you're using Java and Hibernate).

If you don't mean RDS, perhaps you mean EC2? That's the [elastic cloud compute service (EC2)](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). It runs virtual machines. You can then run PostgreSQL on top of those virtual machines if you like. (RDS is internally just an automated version of this that hides all the details and manages it all for you). With EC2+PostgreSQL it's just like PostgreSQL anywhere else, you connect over a normal network socket.

You could also be thinking of the [simple database service, SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/). This is a key/value store. You can't use Hibernate with it. It doesn't have tables. It's a non-relational database. There's also [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), a proprietary non-relational database engine.

The other thing I can think of that you could be meaning is [Redshift, a column-store based on ParAccel that's partially PostgreSQL compatible](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/). Hibernate will work with this, but if you're new to databases you do *not* need Redshift.

If in doubt, use RDS, or perhaps an EC2 instance running PostgreSQL. Host your code in an EC2 instance or adapt it to run on [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).